# How to print a long page on physical printer using java?

Tags: java, printing, printers, thermal-printer

I want to print 1000 line(numbered from 1 to 1000) on a  virtual printer (Microsoft Print to PDF)but it prints only 122 line not more then this.
what I have tried is:
 ***Case 1:***

```
package hindirewr;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 *
 * @author Suthar
 */
public class HelloTRY implements  ActionListener{
    
    
 
PrinterJob pj;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();        
        pj.setPrintable(new BillPrintable(),getPageFormat(pj));
        try {
            
             pj.print();
             
        }
         catch (PrinterException ex) {
                 JLabel label = new JLabel("Printer Exception error !!! Error0019");
            label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
    
public class BillPrintable implements Printable {
    
   
    
    
  public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat,int pageIndex) 
  throws PrinterException 
  {    
      
        
      if (pageIndex>0){     //As i wants to print only one page
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }
      int y=1;
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;                    
            g2d.translate((int) pageFormat.getImageableX(),(int) pageFormat.getImageableY()); 
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN,9));
            try{
                for(int i=0;i<1001;++i){
                g2d.drawString("Line number "+i+" is printed", 50, y);y+=10;
                }
             return PAGE_EXISTS; 
    }
    catch(Exception r){
      JLabel label = new JLabel("r.printStackTrace  !!! Error0019"+r);
            label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,label,"ERROR",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);  
    
    }

              return PAGE_EXISTS;    
              
           
      }
   }
private static Paper paper;
PageFormat pf;
public PageFormat getPageFormat(PrinterJob pj)
{
    
    pf = pj.defaultPage();
    paper = pf.getPaper();    
    double width = 250;      //width
    double height = 10000;      //Paper Height = OneLine*NumberOfLine = 10*1000=10000
    paper.setSize(width, height+50);
    paper.setImageableArea(                    
        0,
        0,
        width,            
        height
    );   
            
    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);          
    pf.setPaper(paper);  
    return pf;
}
    public static void main(String args[]) {
 
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Hello World Printer");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print");
        printButton.addActionListener(new HelloTRY());
        f.add("Center", printButton);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}
```

Output for case one:[image]
,br>It prints only 122 line

***Case 2:***

```
package hindirewr;



import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
import static java.awt.print.Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;

public class TRY2 implements Printable, ActionListener {


    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                        PrinterException {

        if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
            return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
int y=1;
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
        g2d.setFont(new Font("Monospaced",Font.PLAIN,9));
        for(int i=1;i<1000;++i){
        g.drawString("Line number "+i+" is printed", 100, y);y+=10;
        }

        return PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
         job.setPrintable(this);
         boolean ok = job.printDialog();
         if (ok) {
             try {
                  job.print();
             } catch (PrinterException ex) {
              /* The job did not successfully complete */
             }
         }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
 
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Printer");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
           public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
        });
        JButton printButton = new JButton("Print2");
        printButton.addActionListener(new TRY2());
        f.add("Center", printButton);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

It prints Only   101 Lines

             ***How I can Print 1000 Line on a page roll?***

Comment: I have Updated Question with full information

Comment: You're going to have to divide your output lines into pages.  50 lines per page would be appropriate.  You'll have to calculate the page height so that your pages don't leave gaps.

Comment: You mean that there is upper limit on height of Page? As in Question I am giving a perfect height that it required (`double width = 250;      //width
    double height = 10000;      //Paper Height = OneLine*NumberOfLine = 10*1000=10000
    paper.setSize(width, height+50); `) <br>But doesn't work as it is suppose to.

Comment: Look at previous comment . @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: Yes, there's an upper limit on the height and width of a page.

Comment: When I am going for a shorter page like Height =200; and other thing are same the printer create and print(on Physical Printer) a Full Size A4 page.It doesn't stop after height of 200.the Bottom portion (A4 height - 200) print a blank page but i don't want that blank footer.How i can print that much exactly length only @GilbertLeBlanc